# Get pandas data by multiple indices

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have the following data:

```
np.random.seed(42)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))
```

And I wish to grab the values indexed by the rows and columns:

```
rows = [0, 1, 2]
cols = [2, 1, 1]
```

However, doing `data.loc[rows, cols]` gives me the dataframe:

```
        2           1          1
0   0.647689    -0.138264   -0.138264
1   -0.234137   -0.234153   -0.234153
2   -0.469474   0.767435    0.767435
```

Whereas the behaviour that I'm really after is the following:

```
[data.loc[r, c] for r,c in zip(rows, cols)]
>>> [0.6476885381006925, -0.23415337472333597, 0.7674347291529088]
```

What is the correct/ efficient way of doing this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert DataFrame to `2d` numpy array and use fancy indexing:

```
#pandas 0.24+
arr = data.to_numpy()[rows, cols]
#pandas below
arr = data.values[rows, cols]
print (arr)
[ 0.64768854 -0.23415337  0.76743473]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a pandas in-built function, [iat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html).

Running the exact same code you had, and substituting `data.loc` with `data.iat` will generate the output you needed.

```py
np.random.seed(42)
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

rows = [0, 1, 2]
cols = [2, 1, 1]

[data.iat[r, c] for r,c in zip(rows,cols)]

>>> [0.6476885381006925, -0.23415337472333597, 0.7674347291529088]
```